# Ubuntu and Linux Mint and what web development software to use

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

I'm a PHP web developer. I mostly use PHP editors, FTP, multiple web browsers, email (e.g: thunderbird), graphic software etc.

I would like to know which one is the better for **web development** amongst Ubuntu and Linux Mint.

Any feedback and opinions would be appreciated. Also please let me know if you recommend any particular editors and graphic tools like Photoshop.

Thanks.

Comment: I flagged this as not constructive, because "which is the better IDE" is a really charged holy war.

Comment: ["What kind of questions should I not ask here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 1):

From a web development point of view, Ubuntu, Mint and even Debian/Testing are very similar.

You might also consider newer web technologies, like [Opa](http://opalang.org/) or [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) (with Ocaml).

For image processing, Gimp is able of many things...

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, Mint is different in some minor and irrelevant ways such as default desktop environment and add some codecs, preinstall flash... Those things don't have anything to do with web development. So you don't have to think about it :D.
(unless you're talking about LMDE - a new and not ubuntu-based Linux Mint edition).